# A message body writer for Java type, class org.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

Tags: java, json, web-services, maven, pom.xml

I checked many solutions for same question but didn't resolve any. Thats why I am posting again .
When I used POSTMAN its working properly.

I tried with without encoding as well. Then used

> "application/json; charset=utf-8"
>    No any solution I got.

My ClientCode:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException 
            {
                Test1 my_client = new Test1();
                File file_upload = new File("C:/MyJSON.txt");
                my_client.sendFileJSON(file_upload);
            }


            private void sendFileJSON(File file_upload) throws JSONException, IOException{

                ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
               // config.getClass().add(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
                Client client = Client.create(config);
                client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
                WebResource service = client.resource("https://hostedactivation.com/XXXXX/XXXXXXXX.php");


                JSONObject data_file = new JSONObject();
                data_file.put("file_name", file_upload.getName());

                data_file.put("file", convertFileToString(file_upload));
                ClientResponse client_response = service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Authorization", "Basic Y3lDi543XJzcEFsMkJ1Fm0xV2Ic5").post(ClientResponse.class, data_file);
                System.out.println("Status: "+client_response.getEntity(String.class));

                client.destroy();
            }

//Convert my file to a Base64 String
        private String convertFileToString(File file) throws IOException{
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());   
            return new String(Base64.encode(bytes));
        }
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>DataAnalytics</groupId>
    <artifactId>DataAnalytics</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
         <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

MyJSON.txt

```
{
"header":{
"user":"XXXX",
"password": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"table":"licf",
"method_override":"get"
}
}
```

I do not know, something I am missing into it. Any inputs are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What isn't working?  Are you receiving an error?  Please provide more information.

Comment: I changed to all same version number in POM.xml is 1.19 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
   <version>1.19</version>
  </dependency> . I am suffering issue with passing my text file which content JSON type. Please check MyJSON.txt file. If i am not passing this file in post(ClientResponse.class); then its giving me response like: Status: [{"status":"ERROR","message":"JSON decode error"}].

Comment: Your JSON object looks fine.  Do you have access to the server log?  Please post the EXACT error as seen on the server to which you are posting the JSON.

Comment: @LukasBradley No. URL, which I am consuming that 3rd party URL. I am now trying with JACKSON to create JSON object. Ia m not sure it is JSONobject issue or what? Could you please help me to make my JSON into string. I tried but showing compilation error. String input= "{\"header\":"{\"user\":"XXX",\"password\": \"af965a6fcb025b3740cd2dd9af\",\"table\":\"licf\",\"method_override\":\"get\"}}";   So I can check by passing this input directly into post(ClientResponse.class, input)

Comment: Got Result. By using Jackson creating JSON and passing it. Thank you so much for you input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Parent  p = new Parent();
        Header h = new Header();
        h.setUser("XXX");
        h.setPassword("af962d0ceacdd9af");
        h.setTable("licf");
        h.setMethod_override("get");
        p.setHeader(h);

        Test t = new Test();
        String jsonInString = t.writeJSON(p);

         ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
         Client client = Client.create(config);
            client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
            WebResource service = client.resource("https://hostedactivation.com/XXXXX/XXXXXXXX.php");

            ClientResponse client_response = service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                    header("Authorization", "Basic Y3liZXJzcGFI3UGc5").
                    post(ClientResponse.class,jsonInString);

            System.out.println("Status: "+client_response.getEntity(String.class));

            client.destroy();
}
    private String writeJSON(Parent p) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
        return  jsonInString;
       }
```